# What Kind Programming Language Used in File on /system/xbin?

Tags: file-system, linux, android-emulator

i was explore file in xbin folder, then i found that the file is have strange language like this :

```
ELF(   4�Q4   (444  TTT�>�>�M�]�],�LNL^L^hhh88Q�tdpH1H11��R�td�M�]�],,/system/bin/linker
```

And every each file, always start with :

```
ELF
```

so what kind of program is this ? are those code has been compiled before ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at binary compiled file in the 'ELF' format.

From:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

> Android uses ELF .so (shared object) libraries for the Java Native Interface. With Android Runtime (ART), the default since Android 5.0 "Lollipop", all applications are compiled into native ELF binaries on installation.

So that code could have been written in any number of languages.

Comment: so you mean, that elf file could be write on c,c++,or java right ? then, is there any way to change it so that can be readable ?

Comment: The file in a binary file for execution. To learn how the code does what it does you'll need to learn [Assembly Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) in the CPU architecture you are dealing with or find the original source files either in Linux kernel or Android Open Source Project. Further questions along this line is off-topic for this group.

Comment: @user243084: The code in that file has been compiled. That means it's been translated by a "compiler" program from a human-readable programming language, like C or C++ into machine language. Machine language is not readily human-readable. The process of compilation is not reversible: you can't get back to the original human-readable language. To look at the human-readable form of the program, you need to find its source code, and nobody can tell you where to find that unless you tell us the name of the program (and maybe not then).